# Element not being deleted from plsql associative array

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare
    type as_array is table of varchar2(20) index by pls_integer;
    v_fname_array as_array;
    idx           integer;
begin
    for x in 100..105
        loop
            select FIRST_NAME into v_fname_array(x) from EMPLOYEES where EMPLOYEE_ID = x;
        end loop;

    v_fname_array.delete(2, 5);

    idx := v_fname_array.FIRST;

    while idx is not null
        loop
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_fname_array(idx));
            idx := v_fname_array.NEXT(idx);
        end loop;

end;
```

Even after deleting, the output is:

```
Steven
Neena
Lex
Alexander
Bruce
David
```

and count still 6 after & before deleting

Answer (score 2):

Since you are loading elements with indexes 100 to 105, change `v_fname_array.delete(2, 5);` to `v_fname_array.delete(101, 104);`.

The [`DELETE(m,n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-E43509F6-5044-4B17-9516-2EB4BDDD5173) collection method "deletes all elements whose indexes are in the range m..n, if both m and n exist and m <= n; otherwise, it does nothing.".

Comment: If the OP wants to delete the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th indexes of the array then that would be indexes 101...104 (rather than 102...105).